# DELPHI - SOAP Client error - Server was unable to process request

Tags: soap, client

I'm a beginner and trying to retrieve a response from a webservice.

The method (ImportSoap) to send a base64code's pdf and i use a code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
wf:ImportSoap;
res:ArrayOfString;
begin
wf:=(httprio1 as ImportSoap);wf.UploadChunk('*user*','*password*',convertStringToTByteDynArray(Codifica64(Edit1.Text)),res[0],error);
memo1.Lines.Text:=risposta;
end;
```

The error is:
Server was unable to process request - String reference not set to an instance of a String

Server-side code is:

```
  procedure UploadChunk(const userLogin: WideString; const userPassword: WideString; const data: TByteDynArray; out UploadChunkResult: WideString; out errorDescription: WideString); stdcall;
```

Can anyone help me?
(sorry for my english)

Comment: Please add more details about the language stack you are using.

Comment: Im using Delphi 7   - sorry for omissing it

Comment: Tag your question with delphi-7 please. That will help you get an answer quickly. I don't know anything about delphi.